# Covariant relativistic photoelectric effect

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, photoelectric-effect

General textbooks introduce the photoelectric effect as the Einstein's formula
$$hf=hf_0+E_c(max)$$
and where $E_c=mv^2_e/2$ is the kinetic energy maximum value, the work function is $eV_0=hf_0$, and simple derivation follow-up from energy conservation. What would happen if we face with relativistic electrons and atoms. The above textbook equation is not invariant under Lorentz transformations, so I asked myself what would be the SR variant of the above equation, just as we know that de Broglie wavelengh in SR is $\lambda=h/p=h/m\gamma v$ . Could we naively generalize the above expression into a SR variation with 
$E_c=K_m=E_t-E_0=m(\gamma-1)c^2$ and the relativistic photoelectric effect formula would be then:
$$hf=hf_0+mc^2(\gamma-1)=hf_0+E_t-mc^2$$

Comment: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.5052359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the photo effect is also possible at relativistic energies (of the photon). A possible motion of the bound electron is in general not considered, what counts it is the ionisation potential/energy which is for instance -13.5eV for hydrogen. This one is given by a solution of the Schroedinger or Dirac equation for the corresponding bound system (atom). The concept of kinetic energy of the bound electron does not make sense in QM. But the formula you give is correct for high energy photons. To make this formula applicable the photon's energy  has to be  least 100keV which corresponds to a $\gamma \sim 6/5$ (of course it can be also used for lower energy, but then the non-relativistic formula is easier). As it is shown for instance in the 4th volume of Landau/Lifshitz (QED) the photo cross section decreases with increasing energy, in particular in the ultrarelativistic case $\gamma \gg 1$ it is

$$\sigma^{photo}_{tot} \sim \frac{1}{\gamma}$$

where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$ with $v$ the velocity of the escaping electron. But another effect, the Compton effect becomes more dominant. It can be applied for unbound but also for bound electrons (let's say lightly bound with respect to the energy of the photon which is large under these assumptions). In that case as it deals with a scattering of the ingoing photon at the electron, apart from the energy conservation also momentum conservation has to be considered. Considering both conservations the formula describing the kinematics of the Compton-effect is:

$$ \frac{1}{f'}-  \frac{1}{f} = \frac{h}{mc^2}(1-\cos \phi)$$

where $\phi$ is the scattering angle of the photon, $f$ the frequency of the ingoing photon and $f'$ the frequency of the scattered photon and $m$ the mass of the electron. At even higher energy of the photon electron-positron pair production is also possible.